# SQL calculating sum and number of distinct values within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I want to calculate

(1) total sales amount

(2) number of distinct stores per product

in one query, if possible. Suppose we have data:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+
|   store   | product | month | amount |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+
| Anthill   | A       |     1 |      1 |
| Anthill   | A       |     2 |      1 |
| Anthill   | A       |     3 |      1 |
| Beetle    | A       |     1 |      1 |
| Beetle    | A       |     3 |      1 |
| Cockroach | A       |     1 |      1 |
| Cockroach | A       |     2 |      1 |
| Cockroach | A       |     3 |      1 |
| Anthill   | B       |     1 |      1 |
| Beetle    | B       |     2 |      1 |
| Cockroach | B       |     3 |      1 |
+-----------+---------+-------+--------+
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
select 
 [product]
,[month]
,[amount]
,cnt_distinct_stores = count(distinct(stores))
from dbo.temp
group by 
 [product]
,[month]
order by 1,2
```

Would there be possible any combination of `GROUP BY` clause with window functions like `SUM(amount) OVER(partition by [product],[month] ORDER BY [month] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Comment: You seem to condratict yourself. `GROUP BY` aggregates, window function don't (that's why they were introduced), make up your mind - do you want to aggregate or not?

Comment: Let Us Know Your Expected Output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT product,
       SUM(amount),
       COUNT(DISTINCT store)
FROM dbo.temp
GROUP BY product
```